# R ggplot2 facet wrap density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot, facet-wrap

I'm using ggplot to create a facet wrap of histograms + density curves. This is the dataframe I'm plotting (~300 rows):

```
head(merged)
# tpl strand base score ipdRatio     motif
# 1  24501      0    A    51    3.108 AAGTACTCG
# 2  58809      0    A    69    4.095 GAGTACTAC
# 3  65614      0    A    61    3.341 TAGTACTCA
# 4  78494      0    A    92    4.968 GAGTACTAC
# 5  92127      0    A    23    1.702 AAGTACTTA
# 6 193102      0    A    96    5.255 GAGTACTCG
```

Here's a link to the csv file so that you can read the dataframe in yourselves: [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2y3wbpqezxlo82d/merged.csv?dl=0)

If I try this, with nothing but binwidth specified in geom_histogram:

```
# Graph Histogram
ggplot(merged, aes(score)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=25) + 
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~ motif,ncol=7) +
  labs(title=paste("MOTIF:",motif_f),x="Methylation Score",y="Frequency")
```

I get: [image]

However if I try to create density plots for each individual plot by adding `aes(y=..density..)` into geom_histogram like so:

```
# Graph Histogram
ggplot(merged, aes(score)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),binwidth=25) + 
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~ motif,ncol=7) +
  labs(title=paste("MOTIF:",motif_f),x="Methylation Score",y="Frequency")
```

I get an undesired result where the y parameters are stretched out for some plots and cramped for others:
[image]

Any suggestions on how to overlay density plots on these plots while keeping the same y parameters as they are in the first image?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "the y parameters are stretched out for some plots and cramped for others"

Comment: You can see that the y range strangely goes from 0 - 15 in the first image to 0 - 0.04 in the second image. And if you visually compare the plots in the two images, some plots seem vertically stretched out, while others seem vertically condensed

Comment: density isn't on the same scale as counts because its integral will be (~) 1.

Comment: Do you see a way to fix this issue?

Comment: What do you expect to fix? Within a density, the area under the curve will be 1. If you plot counts like in the first place, this has nothing todo with densities. Looks similar but is completely different...

Comment: So is there no way to overlay one on top of the other while pertaining to the histogram y scale?

Comment: as in a way to multiply the density factor to scale it up?

Comment: You could convert your counts in percentage and plot the bars with `geom_bar(stat='identity')` together with your density. I guess this would give you the expected result. I would not scale the density to match the counts.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/280588.html)?